# What wrong with my C# code I'm trying to make object array contain int values from 1 to 100?

Tags: c#, .net, console

Here's code:

```
object[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

Comment: Your code does it.... What is your problem?

Comment: You can't assign an array of type `int` to an array of type `object`

Comment: Why are you using object[] instead of int[]?

Comment: @Eser You better delete yours

Comment: @chomba Yes I did :)

Comment: How would I go about casting an int value 1 - 100 to an object array. I was told a object array can contain both string and int values.

Comment: @user3151548 `Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Select(x=>(object)x).ToList();`

Comment: You can't directly cast from int[] to object[], you'll have use a for loop and cast it one at a time or use Linq as suggested by @Eser. Anyway, you don't really want to use an array of type `object`

Comment: `I was told a object array can contain both string and int values` that is not necessarily a *good* thing.  You are going to have to figure out what they are to use them later.

Comment: Base off Scott's reply this is possible with Enumerable.Cast<T> no need for for-loop to cast every element of object to int. You guys were thinking too hard. I knew there was easier way to do this using C#.

Comment: @user3151548 `Enumerable.Cast<T>` uses a for loop under the covers. Believe me you don't want to use an array of type `object`, what is it that you are trying to accomplish? there surely is a better approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enumerable.Range produces type `int`

You can explicitly convert all the `int`'s to `object`'s by adding a call to [`Enumerable.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
object[] numbers = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).Cast<object>().ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank a lot Scotts! So object array numbers is still an object array right?

Comment: Yes, numbers is an array of objects.  ints are not objects, to there is a technique called "boxing" applied to them so that they may be treated as an object.